# layout element defined globally

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to add a "You are offline" element to the bottom of each layout in my Android app. I would like to define it globally, not to paste the same element to each xml layout file.

I could probably create some ParentActivity and append it programmatically, but is it a good solution?

What is the best way?

Thanks.

Comment: You can do that stuff inside a baseactivity with a specific layout you needed. From that layout you can create fragments and make your other ui logic inside them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best way is creating a custom xml file with any name you want and you can use it any number of times you want without any copy and paste.

step 1: creating custom layout named footer_message .

```
<TextView
  android:layout_width="match_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="You are Offline"/>
```

step 2: adding that custom layout in another xml which you want that msg.

```
<include
        android:id="@+id/footer_message"
        layout="@layout/footer_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use custom [`BottomSheetDialog`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialog). You do not have to inclue it in layout file. Instead, you will call it programmatically.

**BottomMessageDialog:**

```
public class BottomMessageDialog extends BottomSheetDialog {

    public BottomMessageDialog(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_bottom_message);
    }
}
```

**dialog_bottom_message.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="You are offline"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Call it:**

```
BottomMessageDialog bottomMessageDialog = new BottomMessageDialog(MainActivity.this);
bottomMessageDialog.show();
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Looks exactly as I wanted but still it's a dialog. The problem is there is an overlay and after clicking on it the dialog disappears. The elements beneath the overlay are not active anymore...

Answer (score 1):

create an xml file

```
footer.xml
```

make your layout in it  and write this code in the xml files where you want that footer

```
<include
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
layout="@layout/footer" 
android:id="@+id/footer"/>
```

Comment: Looks good. I had a LinearLayout where I tried to include RelativeLayout footer as you suggested. One of the property of the text element "You are offline" is `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`. After I included it to LinearLayout xml file, it wasn't stuck to the bottom anymore.

Comment: I am sorry is this another doubt or you saying it worked. I did not get it